# wtmp contains IP and not hostnames UNIX

Tags: unix

while viewing list of last logins in Unix remote server able to see only IP adresses and not hostnames.
how to define wtmp to show host names and not IP adresses?

Comment: It would be useful to state the type/version of unix the question relates to.

Answer (score 0):

By default, last uses the /var/log/wtmp file for the record of login data.
Wtmp is a file on the Linux operating system that keeps a history of all logins and logouts. On Linux systems, it is located at /var/log/wtmp.

For executing the hostname of [wtmp](https://www.softprayog.in/tutorials/find-user-login-history-last-and-lastb-commands-in-linux) you can try the following command:

```
$ last -5 -F -a -d
```

-F--->the printing of full login and logout dates and times

-a--->we get the hostname in the last column

-d---->displays the hostname instead of its IP address

-5---->number of times to display from last login